# Filter urls by last path with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, url, filtering

I need to filter urls with regex with all last pathes except of several that shoul be skipped. For example:

```
import re

urls_to_exclude = ["example_1", "example_2", "example_3"]

url_1 = "htttps://site.com/api/user/endpath"
url_2 = "htttps://site.com/api/user/other_end?limit=10"
url_3 = "htttps://site.com/api/customer/example_1#tag"
url_4 = "htttps://site.com/api/blog/example_2"

>>> match = re.findall(r"...magic_regex...", url_1)
>>> 'endpath'

>>> match = re.findall(r"...magic_regex...", url_2)
>>> 'other_end'

>>> match = re.findall(r"...magic_regex...", url_3)
>>> 'example_1'

>>> match = re.findall(r"...magic_regex...", url_4)
>>> 'example_2'
```

It should be regex string of compile odject.
Thank you

Comment: Just split the urls by `/`, take the last element (`array[-1]`) and use the `in` operator. No regex needed, really. Additionally, it is not quite clear what you want to do with the urls.

Comment: `urllib.parse.urlparse` will take care of separating the `?foo=bar` and `#whatever` from the path and as @Jan said, you can then split by `'/'` but I prefer using `posixpath.basename`. Why the insistence on using regex? I mean, it can be done but I prefer a simpler/clearer solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try regex, it will not give you the exact last path, but you can easily evaluate using `result[1:-1]`

Regex:
`/[\w\d_-]+[?^"#]`